# jquery ajax - difference in getting data returned from getJson(data) and when(data)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have some ajax code that is working. In the first instance I am using $.when and in the second instance I am using $getJson.

When I use $when I have to reference the returned data as [0]. But when I use $getJson I don't need to get the first element in the array. The json returned from all the calls is the same.

I have been trying to read the documentation as to why this would be so but can't spot where this is noted in the doco. Can someone exaplin to me why there is a difference between the two and where it says this in the doco?

thanks

```
function fetchTranTrends(callback) {
    $.getJSON("service/tranAnalysis/tranTrendsPreviousBusinessDate.json?siteId=" + userStore, function(json) {      
        var data = [];
        data.push(json);
        callback(data);
    }); 
}

function fetchYearlyComparisonData(callback) {

    $.when(fetchThisYearsData(), fetchLastYearsData()).done(function (dataThisYear, dataLastYear) {
        var data = [];
        data.push(dataThisYear[0]);
        data.push(dataLastYear[0]);
        callback(data);
    });
}

function fetchThisYearsData() {         
    return $.getJSON("service/tranAnalysis/tranCountsPreviousSevenDays.json?siteId=" + userStore + "&yearOffset=0", function(json) {}); 
}

function fetchLastYearsData() {
    return $.getJSON("service/tranAnalysis/tranCountsPreviousSevenDays.json?siteId=" + userStore + "&yearOffset=1", function(json) {}); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example given for `when` on jquery documentation.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/#example-0

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
// a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively.
// Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
var data = a1[ 0 ] + a2[ 0 ]; // a1[ 0 ] = "Whip", a2[ 0 ] = " It"
if ( /Whip It/.test( data ) ) {
alert( "We got what we came for!" );
}
});
```

Each argument is an array of the form `a1=[data, statusText, jqXHR]`.

So, you would need to do `a1[0]` to get the data returned by the call.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$.when()` with multiple promises, in such cases each promise might resolve with various number of parameters, so in the callback method it will be difficult to know the param order and the request order.

So what happens in `$.when()` is to group all the arguments of a promise as an array and pass as many arrays as the number of promises to the callbacks